# pointer to array and 2D array representation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have doubt in syntax of pointer to array and 2D array

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void show ( int q[][4], int row )
{
  int i, j ;
  for ( i = 0 ; i < row ; i++ )
  {
     for ( j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++ )
      printf ( "%d ", q[i][j] ) ;
    printf ( "\n" ) ;
  }
  printf ( "\n" ) ;
}

int main( )
{
 int a[][4] = {
                {1, 2, 3, 4},
                {5, 6, 7, 8},
                {9, 0, 1, 6}
              } ;
 show ( a, 3, 4 ) ;
 return 0;
}
```

The above code works with all the below notations

```
void show ( int q[][4], int row )
void show ( int q[3][4], int row )
void show ( int ( *q )[4], int row, int col )

 int q[][4]  == int q[3][4]==int ( *q )[4] // represents pointer to 1D array with size 4
```

I have read this

`int q[ ][4];`
This is same as `int ( *q )[4]`, where `q` is a pointer to an array of 4
integers. The only advantage is that we can now use the more
familiar expression `q[i][j]` to access array elements.

### Question:

The `show()` function works with both of these, `int q[][4]`  and `int q[3][4]` to receive 2D array's address.

But these are representation for 2D array right?

we can't allocate 2D like the following

```
  int (*a)[4] = {                 
                {1, 2, 3, 4},
                {5, 6, 7, 8},
                {9, 0, 1, 6}
              } ;
```

But 2D can be allocated via this statement

```
     int a[][4]={                 
                {1, 2, 3, 4},
                {5, 6, 7, 8},
                {9, 0, 1, 6}
              } ;
```

`int (*a)[4]` is not the same as `int a[][4]`, then how come both 'pointer to array' and '2D array notation' can be used in show function?

Comment: with both `int(*q)[4]`  and int `q[][4]`, `q[i][j]` is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not pointers, but in many situations, arrays decay into pointers, for example when passed as function arguments. So when you pass an `int q[][4]` to a function, the function receives an `int (*q)[4]`, a pointer to arrays of four `int`. That's why both forms work as arguments to `show()`. But for the declaration and initialization, the real type matters, so you can't initialize a pointer with an array-initializer.

Answer (score 2):

Functions have special rules regarding array parameters, the basic rule is if you speak the function's prototype, and your *first word* is array, you change it to "pointer to", so that

```
(int foo[5]) ==> array[5] of int ==> pointer to int
(int foo[][4]) ==> array[] of array[4] of int  ==>  pointer to array[4] of int
(int (*foo)[4]) ==> pointer to array[4] of int ==>  pointer to array[4] of int
(int *argv[]) ==> array of pointer to int ==> pointer to pointer to int
```

Within a function, that conversion doesn't happen, and there is a big difference between array and pointer types.

```
int a[] = {5, 3, 2};
```

Is legal, but

```
int *a = {5, 3, 2};
```

is not. As a rule, **you can't assign a pointer from an array initializer**. Instead, c99 provides compound literals:

```
int *a = (int[]){5, 3, 2};

int (*a)[4] = (int [][4]){
     {2, 2, 3, 1},
     {2, 3, 5, 3},
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First, some language from the C standard:

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
> ...
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of *type*’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to *type*’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

In the call to the `show` function, the *expression* `a` has type "3-element array of 4-element array of `int`".  By the rule above, this expression is *replaced* with an expression of type "pointer to 4-element array of `int`" before the call is made; thus, `show` receives a pointer value of type `int (*)[4]`, not an array.

More standard language:

> **6.7.5.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
> ...
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of *type*’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to *type*’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation. If the keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation, then for each call to the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

Thus, in the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[n]`, `T a[]`, and `T *a` are all equivalent.  If `T` is an array type, such as "4-element array of `int`", then `int a[3][4]`, `int a[][4]`, and `int (*a)[4]` are all equivalent.

Note that this is *only* true for function parameter declarations.  When you're declaring an array *object*, the following language comes into play:

> **6.7.8 Initialization**
> ...
> 22 If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer. At the end of its initializer list, the array no longer has incomplete type.

So when you write

```
int a[][4] = {
            {1, 2, 3, 4},
            {5, 6, 7, 8},
            {9, 0, 1, 6}
          } ;
```

you are declaring an Nx4 array of `int`, not a pointer to an array of `int` -- the inner dimension 3 is inferred from the number of 4-element arrays in the initializer.